# harvesting data from ckan instance

Tags: data-analysis, ckan

I am harvesting data from ckan instance and collecting in an other ckan instance. I am totally new to this subject. Though I am able to harvest datasets in my ckan instance, but I am not able to understand the next step, how to do pretreatment and postreatment of data, what should be my next step? Here is the screenshot of my current collection of datasets.

[image: screenshot link]

Please suggest how should I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own "harvester", probably taking the CKAN harvester as a basis and change it for your needs.

Instructions here:
https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-harvesting-interface

The import_stage is what you want to add to.